# Loading Django application's setting under an apparmor profile

Tags: python, linux, django, security, apparmor

So we have a django application that requires an apparmor profile (client mandate). It runs in a Python virtual environment located in `/opt/fact-virtual-environment`. The application itself installs into `/usr/share/fact`

The following is my profile so far (built mostly with the aa-genprof tool):

```
# Last Modified: Tue Jan 20 09:25:09 2015
#include <tunables/global>

/usr/bin/fact flags=(audit) {
  #include <abstractions/apache2-common>
  #include <abstractions/base>
  #include <abstractions/bash>


  capability setgid,
  capability sys_resource,

  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/**/ rm,
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/** rm,
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/**/ rm,
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/** rm,
  /etc/apparmor.d/** r,
  #/usr/lib/python2.7/**[^/] r,

  /usr/bin/sudo Ux,

  #/usr/bin/strace ux,
  /bin/bash rix,
  /bin/dash rix,
  /bin/uname rix,
  /dev/tty rw,
  /etc/default/locale r,
  #/etc/nsswitch.conf r,
  #/etc/group r,
  #/etc/passwd r,
  /etc/environment r,
  /etc/login.defs r,
  /etc/lsb-release r,
  /etc/fact/fact.ini r,
  /etc/python2.7/sitecustomize.py r,
  /etc/security/pam_env.conf r,
  /lib{,32,64}/** mr,
  /opt/fact-virtual-environment/**/ mr,
  /opt/fact-virtual-environment/lib/python2.7/**/ mr,
  /opt/fact-virtual-environment/lib/python2.7/** mr,
  /opt/fact-virtual-environment/bin/python rix,
  /run/utmp rk,
  /sbin/ldconfig rix,
  /sbin/ldconfig.real rix,
  /usr/bin/fact rix,
  /usr/lib{,32,64}/** mr,
  /usr/share/fact/**/ r,
  /usr/share/fact/** r,
  /usr/share/pyshared/** r,
  /usr/share/pyshared/**/ r,
}
```

...and the `/usr/bin/fact` command is a simple wrapper:

```
#!/bin/bash

## This script is for running the 'fact' command on staging/prod, it sudos to
## the 'fact' user before executing /opt/fact/bin/fact

## It is installed as '/usr/bin/fact'

PYTHONPATH=/usr/share/fact
PYTHON_BIN=/opt/fact-virtual-environment/bin/python
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=fact.settings.staging

if [ "$USER" != "fact" ];
then
  sudo -u fact $0 $*;
else
  PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH} DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=${DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE}  ${PYTHON_BIN} -m fact.managecommand $*;
fi
```

I've enabled a lot of read permissions I know I don't need, like the entire `/usr/local/lib/*` set in a debugging attempt. Something that strikes me as very off about this entire thing is that my profiles don't seem to get reloaded when I run `service apparmor reload` (or restart). I seem to get different results if I restart the service versus `aa-complain usr.bin.fact` followed by `aa-enforce usr.bin.fact`.

Right now when I run my command and check the system logs, I see the following:

```
Feb 11 15:08:48 spiffy kernel: [1228245.774660] type=1400 audit(1423620528.359:14142): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=12884 profile="/usr/bin/fact" name="/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/" pid=12885 comm="python" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=111 ouid=0
Feb 11 15:08:48 spiffy kernel: [1228245.774855] type=1400 audit(1423620528.359:14143): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=12884 profile="/usr/bin/fact" name="/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/" pid=12885 comm="python" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=111 ouid=0
Feb 11 15:08:48 spiffy kernel: [1228245.775829] type=1400 audit(1423620528.359:14144): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=12884 profile="/usr/bin/fact" name="/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/" pid=12885 comm="python" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=111 ouid=0
```

..and my python application barfs:

```
$ fact
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/share/fact/fact/managecommand.py", line 6, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/fact-virtual-environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/fact-virtual-environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/opt/fact-virtual-environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 46, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/opt/fact-virtual-environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/opt/fact-virtual-environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 98, in __init__
    % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
ImportError: Could not import settings 'fact.settings.staging' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): cannot import name current_app
```

That setting file it's looking for is located at `/usr/share/fact/fact/settings/staging.py`

I am totally beyond confused on why I can't get this application to run under its apparmor profile. The settings in the configuration file should allow it. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the denials are looking for this specific directory: `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`

Your profile includes some children of this directory:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/**/ rm,
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/** rm,
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/**/ rm,
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/** rm,
```

But it doesn't include this specific directory. So add this to your profile, reload the profile, and try again:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ r,
```

AppArmor uses the trailing `/` to determine if the administrator intended to allow getting directory listings versus allowing a file to be read.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

your profile is missing permissions to read the directory
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

you will need to add
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/  r,

the permissions your current profile have allow access to everything under /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ but not actual access to the directory itself